# Why doesn't the typeguard prevent object is possibly 'undefined' error

Tags: typescript

I have a partial which is an object whose keys are derived from an enum. To prevent the unexpected access of properties on undefined (if the partial object does not have the key), I use a typeguard to check before moving on. However even within the typeguard, TypeScript still throws and error. Why is this / What did I get wrong?

```
export enum SupportedAsset {
  DAI = "DAI",
  ETH = "ETH",
}

interface Transaction {
    asset: SupportedAsset;
}

export enum Fiat {
  USD = "USD",
}

export interface HistoricalFxRate {
  rate: string; // "1.001"
  base: SupportedAsset;
}

type Rates = Record<SupportedAsset, HistoricalFxRate[]>

const rates: Partial<Rates> = {
      DAI: [
        {
          base: SupportedAsset.DAI,
          rate: "1.001",
        },
      ]
    };

function foo(rates: Partial<Rates>, transactions: Transaction[]) {
    transactions.map((txn) => {
        if (rates[txn.asset]) {
            rates[txn.asset][0]; // TYPE ERROR: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: There are several previous questions on this (not that they're necessarily easy to find), I'll see if I can find one to point to. Basically: TypeScript can only narrow constant expressions (or something like that). So `const x = rates[txn.asset]; if (x) { x[0]; }` would work, but not the above. It's just a pragmatic limitation of the compiler to prevent it running really slowly. :-)

Comment: Ah thanks for the explanation and and link!